# Run Intellij IDEA 2019 JUnit tests with a JUnit4 runner instead of JUnit5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, powermock

I want to start *com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter* with a junit4 runner instead of junit5, editing program arguments for tests are no longer supported in Intellij, and by default it appends -junit5 as program argument, leading to *com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner* getting picked.

Setting system property **-Didea.is.junit5**=false is of no use, as it gets overriden by -junit5 check as per the source code here

```
private static String processParameters(Vector args, final List listeners, String[] params) {

    String agentName = isJUnit5Preferred() ? JUNIT5_RUNNER_NAME : JUNIT4_RUNNER_NAME;
    Vector result = new Vector(args.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
      String arg = (String)args.get(i);
      if (arg.startsWith(IDE_VERSION)) {
        //ignore
      }
      else if (arg.equals(JUNIT3_PARAMETER)){
        agentName = JUNIT3_RUNNER_NAME;
      }
      else if (arg.equals(JUNIT4_PARAMETER)) {
        agentName = JUNIT4_RUNNER_NAME;
      }
      else if (arg.equals(JUNIT5_PARAMETER)) {
        agentName = JUNIT5_RUNNER_NAME;
      }
    .
    .
```

I have a use-case around initiating the tests with a junit4 runner then handing it over to *JUnitPlatform* class so that jupiter does it work.

Annotations over my test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitPlatform.class)
```

Overall idea is to utilize the magic of *PowerMockRunner* to mock static methods via junit4, then delegate it to *JUnitPlatform*.
Right now, the *PowerMockRunner* is not getting picked because the runner is junit5 as mentioned above.

Comment: What if you remove all dependencies to JUnit 5 modules from your classpath, does IJ still use the JUnit5 runner?

Comment: Do you need both Junit4 and Junit5 in the project?

Comment: Yes I need both, as there is no support for Powermock in JUnit5. And the tests are written in spock using groovy 3.0, which comes with the junit5 engine. I'm able to start the tests with junit4 and able to mock statics in similar settings, via maven surefire plugin, but that only works via terminal.